# astro pagination for year wise listing

Tags: pagination, astrojs

I have a Astro blog with pagination and it is working.(santm.com)

```
/blog/
/blog/1/
/blog/2/
```

I also created [year].astro which list posts for 2022, 2021, 2020

so I get
`/blog/2022/ blog/2021/ blog/2020/`

But I want a pagination within year as there might be long lists ; how I do that ? or that is not possible as for pagination to work the filename have to be **[page].astro** or [...page].astro

I tried calling the current pagination component which works from **/src/pages/blog/[year].astro** and did not work

Comment: did you try this https://docs.astro.build/en/core-concepts/routing/#pagination, can you post your example.

Comment: I did and that is where my question *is not possible as for pagination to work the filename have to be [page].astro or [...page].astro*

Comment: page is just a variable name, year is also a variable name. If you need closer support, you might want to share a reproduction example to help people find where your issue is and help you.

Comment: SOLVED it for now for the authors part ; so i think I will be able to solve it for years as well. 
**Astro currently does not support multiple dynamic parameters in a single file name.**

What I did for the Authors is 
`src/pages/authors/[author]/[...page].astro` and this way pagination works. It is not perfect now i understood what needs to be done ; will do it for **tags** and **years**.

thanks